# White line in the middle of the video in Da Vinci resolve

Tags: davinci-resolve

I exported my video in Da Vinci resolve but there's a white line in the middle of the screen. I was thinking that it was probably the effect but i'm not sure. Does anyone have the same problem or could help me to resolve it ?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Video Production Stack Exchange.  You'll need to provide more information about your situation before we'll be able to help you.  What are the specs of the computer you're using?  What operating system and OS version are you running?  What version of Resolve (Free or Studio? Version number?)  And if you haven't already, you should ask over at https://forum.blackmagicdesign.com be sure to include that information over there as well.  See their troubleshooting FAQ:  https://forum.blackmagicdesign.com/viewtopic.php?f=21&t=90190 They are a very helpful community.

Comment: And if you could post a screenshot of the line on the screen, that would be helpful, too.

Comment: When you say, "it was probably the effect," what effect have you applied?  You might try exporting a different video format.  I've run across some bugs with Fusion alpha channels (which you might be using whether you know it or not, depending on the effects you've applied) in h.264 exports on Resolve 16.2 for Mac.  I fixed by switchiing to Prores 4444 export, then transcoding to h.264.